# C++ private modifier ignored on nested anonymous struct

Tags: c++, nested, private, access-modifiers, anonymous-struct

The following sample code compiles just fine in Visual C++:

```
class Test {
private:
    struct {
        struct {
            int privateData;
        };
    };
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    Test test;
    test.privateData = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

But why? I'd expect a compiler error because the `privateData` member should be inaccessible to the function main, since it's supposed to be `private` like its container's container.
I know that nameless structs are not part of official C++, but this design is asinine.

By the way I've also tried to change `private` into `protected` and `struct` into `union`: it looks like the compiler refuses to honor access modifiers on anonymous structs and unions that are nested inside another anonymous struct or union.

Can someone explain this feature?

Comment: This sounds like the bug that was fixed in _VS2005sp1_, which version are you using? Keep in mind that _anonymous structs_ are not a standard _C++_ feature...

Comment: @K-ballo gcc also compiles this...

Comment: BTW, the intellisense does complain but it nevertheless compiles

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: That doesn't make them any more standard...

Comment: @K-ballo I never said that, just pointing out a fact...

Comment: Clang 4.0 does not compile this with an error "error: 'privateData' is a private member of 'Test'"

Comment: private applies to the name of a struct (and in no way to the struct itself or its content, really just the name). For an unnamed struct, it is not completely obvious what happens.

Comment: It works correctly if you put `private:` in the first anonymous struct and then nest however many anonymous structs beneath it.  The answer seems to be: "it's a bug."

Comment: Also interesting is the fact that the MSDN entry on anonymous structures gives code that can't compile (at least in 2008): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: `test.privateData` shouldn't even exist! Where is an instance of those un-named structs?

Comment: @K-ballo: Unnamed structs are not standard...?! Then explain `[C++11: 9/1]: [..] A class-specifier whose class-head omits the class-head-name defines an unnamed class.`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Oh, so are they standard now in _C++11_? That's a change that slipped under my radar...

Comment: @K-ballo: The `identifier` is optional in C++03 too, AFAICT (though the same explicit wording is not present, 9.4.2/5 and 3.5/4 both make direct reference to "unnamed classes"). I've never heard of this being non-standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f.aspx I'm guessing it needs to be updated now? Or are we talking about different things? Note this is not _just_ about a struct with no name

Comment: @K-ballo: It seems to me that this page needed to be updated fifteen years ago. Let's not use MSDN as an authoritative source on what is and isn't standard C++...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ok then, do the _unnamed classes_ in the standard (both 03 and 11) have its members in the enclosing struct or class as _anonymous classes_? Note anonymous != unnamed

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Now a quick check of the _C++11_ standard seems to suggest that while _anonymous unions_ are still allowed, _anonymous structs_ are still not... You seem to be confusing _unnamed_ with _anonymous_... Think _anonymous namespace_...

Comment: @K-ballo: I don't see any distinction between unnamed and anonymous. I started [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard) to address this.

Comment: For the record -- that other Q&A concludes that I was wrong :)

Comment: @JCooper when I put `private:` in the first anonymous struct VS 2012  complains because of a syntax error in the struct definition, not because of the access to a private member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug.  Microsoft acknowledged it is, the feedback report [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520784/access-to-private-fields-inside-anonymous-unions-and-structs-is-strangely-relaxed).

Right now the bug is in "will not fix" status and it is unclear when (if ever) it will be addressed.  There is a somewhat odd workaround for it, the IntelliSense parser built into Visual Studio, written by the Edison Design Group, does complain about it.  You get the red squiggles and the message:

> Error: member "Test.privateData" (declared at line 10) is inaccessible

Comment: Are you suggesting that there are hordes of developers displaced in time who _rely_ on access specifiers not properly cascading through two levels of anonymous structs?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My understanding is there aren't hordes, but a pack that like to use microsoft's "workarounds", and for these people they do not fix this and similar issues. Instead, they mark it with their code parser

Comment: @BЈовић: It just seems to me like an _incredibly_ narrow edge case that wouldn't be worth such considerations, _even_ when there's also arguably little benefit in fixing it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good. We agree :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit like Luchian Grigore notes in a comment to the question, this "bug" can be successfully reproduced in gcc. In my understanding, this is by no means a matter of chance and compatibility requirements could likely be a good reason in support of the current design.

Comment: It is a bit remarkable that Microsoft agrees that GCC has a bug.  I should have stuck with my original answer but got too much flak about it. Tends to happen when Lightness throws around his weight.

Comment: @Hans: I didn't give you any "flak". I asked a follow-up question. Let's leave the personal attacks aside, okay?

Comment: @ft1: Okay that seems like a reasonable interpretation